# HTML Form not sending any data to Laravel serverside

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to upload a file using a form and Laravel. My form:

```
<form action="testUpload" nctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
  <input type="hidden" name="_Token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 25px">
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="custom-file">
           <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
           <label class="custom-file-label" id="uploadFile" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
       </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
 </div>
</form>
```

My route is as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){
    Route::post('/testUpload', 'uploadController@upload');
});
```

And my controller:

```
public function upload(){
    $data = Request::all();
    return $data;
}
```

Currently, I am getting a 419 Page Expired error when pressing the button. What am I missing? I have tried clearing all my route cache

Answer (score 1):

You are missing CSRF field in your form. All forms should have it.
You can add it easy with `@csrf` between `<form>` and `</form>`

Note: `nctype='multipart/form-data'` should be `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: this question has been answered tons of times before. Rather tag a duplicate